# How to configure begin and end date of SPELL in TraMineR

Tags: r, traminer

In the SPELL format of TraMineR, for a given individual i, should end date at t and start date at t+1 be the same or incremented by 1?

My dataset is built this way:

```
id | start  |   end   | state
1  | 2/1/12 | 3/6/12  | "a"
1  | 3/6/12 | 1/14/13 | "b"
1  | 1/14/13| 2/2/13  | "c"
```

Should I add 1 day to each start beginning at row 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `seqformat` function of `TraMineR` expects integer values as begin and end arguments. If you provide dates, their corresponding integer values will be considered.

Now, `seqformat` has an `overwrite` argument that permits to control the handling of overlaps. By setting `overwrite = FALSE`, you get the results that you would obtain by adding 1 day to the start values of your second and third rows. With the default `overwrite = TRUE`, the most recent episode overwrites the older one when they overlap.